# Installing Android 10 with a Device Specific Binary

Tags: android-10

So I got my hands on a Android 10 binary that was designed for a Samsung Galaxy 10. Can I install it on a different phone? I have a Motorola g7 Power, so it should be compatible with the OS but I am not sure if the device specific version would cause any issues.

Comment: Probably not. Built in to the AOSP image is device specific settings, drivers, essentially, that are necessary to support the hardware on that phone. Android has to be compiled for each phone model and submodel specifically.

Comment: That depends which libraries are used by the executable file. If only non-Samsung specific libraries and services are used it may work. Anyway when asking such questions you should be more specific what binary you are trying to execute and what it is supposed to do.